# OpenCV FileStorage - how to use in C# with EmguCV?

Tags: c#, opencv, persistence, emgucv

Is it possible to rewrite examples from [XML/YAML Persistence page](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html) from [OpenCV](http://opencv.itseez.com/index.html) to [EmguCV](http://file.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)?
I mean code in first two subchapters: *"XML/YAML file storages. Writing to a file storage"* and *"Reading data from a file storage."*

I am mostly interested in saving and loading `int`-s and sequences.

I have found [EmguCV cvOpenFileStorage](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/4fec74c3-3f3d-4bce-95d9-d049c937ff0c.htm) doc - most arguments are `IntPtr`s and it is not clear for me how to use it for mentioned types (concerning matrices - I have found working examples).

Comment: +1 I see this is really old, but I am looking (unsuccessfully) for the exact answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Emgu does not support completely the OpenCV functions related to FileStorage operations: you must wrap the missing methods using Interop (System.Runtime.InteropServices). 
At the following link you can find a code example: http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1877